# Ajax Affect Page After Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a quick question. Can i affect redirected page with ajax's success function? Code will explain better

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/admin/done",
            data: {            
                "title": title,
                "description" : description,
                "person" : person,
                "date" : date
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(json) {          
                window.alert(json.jobTitle + " created");
                //window.location.replace("/admin");        
                window.location.href = '/admin';  
                $('#createAlert').css("visibility","inherit");
                $('#createMessage').text("New word");
            }
        });
```

I have some components in admin.html. Im redirecting page after ajax success but i want to do some changes after success. Its like a popup message. I dont want to use "window.alert" because it looks bad. If my ajax func can affect the redirected page, it will be better.

## ADMIN.HTML

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="createAlert" style="visibility:hidden">
            <strong>Success!</strong>
            <p id="createMessage">Job</p>
        </div>
```

At the beginning they are invisible because user has to create before, then popup should be shown.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do this with JQuery/Javascript as these are run clientside and refreshed on each page load, you would loose the set variable.

You could however store a small variable in localstorage and fetch that on the pageload of admin.html and do some action with it, you you really want to pass some information to another page using only javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Note that localstorage works only on the domain, so you would still loose the data if you redirect to another domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer